# Exec function not working in AGI Script:

Tags: asterisk

I am calling AGI SCRIPT from my dialplan and using exec function to call sh script but it is not working. Why ? Is it possible to call sh script using agi script ?

```
$agi->exec("sh count_length.sh '/SOUND/shakti.gsm'" );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using [phpAGI](http://phpagi.sourceforge.net/)

The exec function is to "execute" an Asterisk application when called as `$agi->exec()`. It's really intended to be used for a regular asterisk application, for example to playback a sound you would issue:

`$agi->exec("Playback","demo-congrats");`

From an Asterisk dialplan (not specifically through AGI) if you want to execute a system call, you use the `SYSTEM` application. Check out the help on it by issuing at the asterisk CLI:

`asterisk*CLI> core show application System`

But! I think what you're really going to want to do is shell out to your system using PHP's built-in methods of doing so. You'll get more finite control, and it's probably the most efficient way of doing it.

The way I typically do that is to use this function from [the PHP manual page for `system()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)

```
function syscall($command){
    if ($proc = popen("($command)2>&1","r")){
        while (!feof($proc)) $result .= fgets($proc, 1000);
        pclose($proc);
        return $result; 
        }
    }
```

Then you can call it like:

```
<?php
  $result = syscall("/path/to/count_length.sh '/SOUND/shakti.gsm'");
?>
```